# What is this compromised-looking result under the google.co.uk main search result?

Tags: google

I noticed this where it used to say something about the search engine.
I noticed it when searching for "google".

[image]

Has Google been compromised or something? I am not going to click this link to see what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's kind of Easter Egg of Google.

If you change language code in `hl` parameter to `xx-hacker` then you will get [1337 speak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) at many places on result.

It's [safe](https://www.google.com/?hl=xx-hacker)

Comment: I get the same results by searching for "google hacker". https://www.google.com/search?q=google+hacker  It's just a bit of fun,

Comment: @schroeder: That because `hacker` word is being found in `hl` parameter. That's the first result you will get.